# UI Button "if" statement in swift

Tags: swift, if-statement, error-handling

when I type the code in, there is an error saying this:

picture of the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixFaM.png

How can I fix it?

```
 @IBAction func nextQuestionButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if (nextQuestionButton.isSelected == true) {
            
        }
```

Comment: Do you use `sender` or `nextQuestionButton` ? xcode 13.0 has a well known lagging , re-compile

Comment: i use nextQuestionButton

Answer (score 4):

use UIButton in your @IBAction method like below

```
@IBAction func nextQuestionAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.isSelected {
        // returns true value
    }
    else 
    {
       // returns false value
    }
}
```

or

```
@IBAction func nextQuestionAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if ((sender as AnyObject).isSelected) {
        // returns true value
    }
    else 
    {
       // returns false value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a misunderstanding.

`nextQuestionButton` is **not** the button, it's an **action** connected to the button. The button is represented by the `sender` parameter.

This syntax makes it clearer

```
@IBAction func nextQuestionAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.isSelected {
        
    }
}
```